# Concatenate on form input id, doesnt work in C#

Tags: asp.net, input, concatenation

I'm using C# on an input id from ASP form.
The `id` name is: `SpecialValue`. I'm also using JavaScript to dynamically add more values (`SpecialValue2`, `SpecialValue3` and so on). When trying to read from the variables, I'm getting an error with this example of concatenation.

Can someone please explain why?

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
{        
    if ("SpecialValue" +i+.Value == null)
         break;
}
```

Comment: Don't post code that doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

First, in C# a single quote is used for a literal *character*, not a string.  You **must** use double quotes for a string.  See:  [What's the difference between double quotes and single quote in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602033/whats-the-difference-between-double-quotes-and-single-quote-in-c-sharp)

Second, "SpecialValue" + i + creates a literal string:  "SpecialValue2", "SpecialValue3", etc.

Your if statement is then trying to access the Value property of a literal string:  `"SpecialValue2".Value`.  String objects don't have a Value property.

Instead, you need to pass your literal string value in the `Request.Form` collection:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["SpecialValue" + i.ToString()]))
    break;
```

See:  [How to access html form input from asp.net code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind)

Also, note the use of `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, which will return true if the value is null, "", or " ".

Comment: And if you are allowed to change the form, you can set the name of all of the values to be the same.  The input name could all be "SpecialValue".  Then `Request.Form.GetValues("SpecialValue")` would return an array of values you could loop through.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```
 for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
  {        
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["SpecialValue" +i.ToString()]))
     break;
```

}

Reasoning for this is that you can not concatinate string and integer(i) in C#, you need to convert integer to string first. Second you need to get value from your variables by request and String.IsNullOrEmpty allows you to make sure that it is not null or empty-returns false if any value there.In your case if it null or empty it will return true and goes to break