# C# syntax ' " + stringName + " '

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, string, textbox

What does  `' " + stringName + " '` mean in c#  ? I thought in programming if you enclose something withing quotes it will be treated as string.Some detail would be appreciated as i have just started learning c#

Code :

```
string sql_insertQuery = "INSERT into UserData(username,password,country) VALUES ('"+Usn.Text+"','lpxt','l.Text')";
```

Usn is the Id of a textbox, I am just testing right now but i know inputting information like this is not recommended because of SQL Injection

Edit : I understand the answers provided  below about concatenation but why do i get error if i use

```
string sql_insertQuery = "INSERT into UserData(username,password,country) VALUES ("+Usn.Text+",'lpxt','l.Text')";
```

double quotes only

and why does using single quotes pass +Usn.Text+ as the input string

```
 string sql_insertQuery = "INSERT into UserData(username,password,country) VALUES ('+Usn.Text+','lpxt','l.Text')";
```

Comment: It is just a string concatenation. `string1 + string2`

Comment: You can pass SqlParameter instead to avoid Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Usn.Text is enclosed within one single quote and one double
>   quote(double quotes within single quotes)

#### No.

This value is enclosed *only* single quotes since your `username` column is character typed.

But double quotes are for string concatenation for this these 3 strings;

```
"INSERT into UserData(username,password,country) VALUES ('"
Usn.Text
"','lpxt','l.Text')"
```

As you said, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

> Edit : I understand the answers provided below about concatenation but
>   why do i get error if i use

You didn't *even* tell us what error you get but I assume you try to insert your `username` character typed column, you *have to* use single quotes with it. Of course, if you use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), you can skip those quotes.

> and why does using single quotes pass +Usn.Text+ as the input string

Because when you write `VALUES ('+Usn.Text+','lpxt','l.Text')"`, you insert your `+Usn.Text+` as a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), It will not insert it's `Text` value, it will insert `+Usn.Text+` as a string.

For example, if `Usn.Text = "foo";` you will *not* insert that `foo` string, you will insert `+Usn.Text+` in such a case.

Comment: By the way, this is a classical sample how not to do SQL queries. Imagine Usn.Text has value "Robert'); DROP TABLE UserData". Executing this SQL query after using it will remove tabe UserData

Comment: Yep i see (reading "i will always refresh page before posting" mantra)

Comment: why is is necessary to put single quotes? and the error with double quotes was  : Invalid column name "whatiTypedInTextBox"

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal Because it is a rule for character typed columns in SQL. Your error message means; there is no column as `whatiTypedInTextBox`. Check your query twice.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the text inside the "Usn"-Control will be included into your SQL-query. Yet the String within the query will be surrounded by ''.

Like in this example:

```
    string stringVariable = "myString";
    Console.WriteLine("'" + stringVariable + "'");
```

Here the output will be:

> **'myString'**

Notice how the output is surrounded by the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The **plus operator** **is used for** **string concatenation**.
More can be read at the documentation/guide.
Excerpt from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx:

> **Concatenation** is the process of **appending one string to the end of
>   another** string. When you concatenate string literals or string
>   constants **by using the + operator**, t**he compiler creates a single
>   string.** No run time concatenation occurs. However, string variables
>   can be concatenated only at run time. In this case, you should
>   understand the performance implications of the various approaches.

EDIT (since the question has been edited):
Since the double qotes and the + are in qotes, they won't be processed by the compiler and therefore be handled as strings. so you would literally add  `" + stringName + "` to the database

A good explanation of single and double qotes can be found here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/602035/3948598

> Single quotes encode a single character (data type char), while double
>   quotes encode a string of multiple characters. The difference is
>   similar to the difference between a single integer and an array of
>   integers.

Comment: I think the link you provided _can_ be confusing from OP side since there is a difference single quotes usage between C# and SQL. In C#, it is for `char` type which can be contains only one UTF-16 character but in SQL, it is for character typed columns which can be contains more than one character as `'foo'`.