# UnRecognised escape sequence in a string is throwing error in the replace method of the string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string name which has `-` as a special character which has to be replaced by `\-`.

```
 name = name .Contains('-') ? name .Replace('-', '\-') : name;
```

The replace method throws error of unrecognized escape sequence.

When i try to  do this

```
name = name .Contains('-') ? name .Replace('-', '\\-') : name;
```

too many characters in character literal.

Some example of name is :

```
abc-123-45g
xyz-1-2-3
ref-124
```

What is the best way to replace the character?

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: You don't need to use method `.Contains(...)`, just use `.Replace(...)`

Comment: As @freefaller has eluded to, the apostrophe in C# represents a single character while the quotation mark represents a string - which is what "\-" is. It is better explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/602035/2474700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `\-` is not a character. its a string.

So you should use the overload the takes strings not characters:

```
name = name.Contains('-') ? name.Replace("-", "\\-") : name;
```

Also you don't really need that `Contains` condition. So you end up with:

```
name = name.Replace("-", "\\-");
```

Comment: I think the `Contains` condition was there to avoid creating/allocating a new `string`, in case no characters were replaced. I ran a test using VS2017 Diagnostic Tools / Memory Usage and can confirm there is no new string allocation (if no characters are replaced)