# Difference between ''Y" and 'Y' C#

Tags: c#

Hi does somebody know what is the difference between "" and '' in c#.
I've tried searching the web but I've found nothing.
Thx for the answers.

Comment: `"` is for `string` literals, `'` is for `char` literals.

Comment: @TomTom How exactly do you search for "the difference between ' and ""? That's actually quite tricky, especially if you don't know what `'` and `"` are called in words (which is likely the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Y" is a string, and 'Y' is a char.

Single quotes encode a single character (data type char), while double quotes encode a string of multiple characters. The difference is similar to the difference between a single integer and an array of integers.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602033/whats-the-difference-between-double-quotes-and-single-quote-in-c-sharp)